# Multiple css for multiple resolutions - image resizing problems

Tags: css

I'm programming my website and I wanted to create different css for different resolutions.
I've done this by following the tutorial up there: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Everything done correctly, but when my window resizes for the narrow css, all images are big.

1 Question: How can I resize them in the css?
2 Question: If I don't want to show some div in the narrow style, using "display: none;" will block it from loading or it just hide it?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Answer to second question: the DOM-elements inside your container which has `display:none;` still gets loaded (you can see it in the sourceode of the page in your browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good article to read through. It's one of the better articles I've read about "responsive web design." http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

This might also help with fluid images in case you wanted to dynamically resize images through the use of the following:

```
img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Not super IE friendly from the sounds of it, but workarounds are explained in the article. 
http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

---

This is the final result of the first "A List Apart" article... pretty well done IMO. Try resizing your browser to see how it adjusts. http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this for resizing images

```
#my_image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

To answer your second question, `display: none` [just hides it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099637/does-displaynone-keep-elements-from-loading). The image will be downloaded