# Does hiding a div load the information?

Tags: html, hide

Just wondering if when i display a div as hidden does the information gete loaded then hidden or does it get loaded when it is shown? can't remember the ters but it's like display="none" or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is similar to yours.  [Does display:none keep elements from loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099637/does-displaynone-keep-elements-from-loading)

The part that relates to your question is this ->

> Nope. display: none will only prevent the element from being
>   displayed; it will be loaded nevertheless.
>
> You can watch this happen in the element inspector of your choice
>   (e.g. in Firebug or IE8's dev tools).
>
> The best way is probably to create the Video element using JavaScript
>   afterwards, or - if you want a fail-safe solution in case JS is turned
>   off - you could use an iframe that loads the video if the user clicks
>   a link.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It still gets loaded into the DOM, but the browser doesn't show it since there is a hint to hide it.
Just use a DOM inspector like IE deveopler tools to inspect it, and you will see it with `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of CSS styles that you can use to hide the information from being displayed.

`display: none` and `visibility: hidden`

Both of them will actually **load the DOM content** but does not display them.`visibility: hidden`  takes the space required for that DOM element accordingly in the layout eventhough it does not display the element. But `display: none` considers that the element is not present in the DOM and does not occupy any space in DOM corresponding to that element.

Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/ADSmc/